# MYSQL no route to host

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked through the others that use these words.  Not applicable.  I have two machines plugged into the same switch with IP's of 192.168.0.7 and .10.  7 is the client.  10 is the server.  I've checked netstat on the server and it is showing:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.10:3306       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I can ping, sftp and so forth in both directions from either machine.  The PHP itself is as follows:

```
$host = "192.168.0.10";
$user = "web";
$pass = redacted;
$db = "appliance";
// open connection
$connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
  echo "Error: Failed to make a MySQL connection, here is why: \n";
  echo "Errno: " . $connection->connect_errno . "\n";
  echo "Error: " . $connection->connect_error . "\n";
  exit;
}
```

I get this at the browser (3rd machine - same network):

> Error: Failed to make a MySQL connection, here is why: Errno: 2002
>   Error: No route to host

I've even tried adding the explicit port argument.  Same error.
I don't even know where to look at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Can You execute this code in both CLI and HTTP environment? 
If apache has problem, therefore in cli there was no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the firewall on your MySQL server is blocking port 3306. For me it caused the 'No route to host' error.

Answer (score -2):

check your connection to remote and check remote's firewall.

and check bind address in remote my.ini

Comment: It doesn't appear you read the information given, or you wouldn't have suggested any of these.  I've already established that connectivity is possible via other techniques.  Firewall blocking wouldn't generate the error of 'no route to host'.  The netstat output establishes the port is correctly configured and listening.

Comment: More information.  I setup a simple TCP echo server on the same machine (the server at .10) and wrote a PHP client for it.  I get the same 'no route to host' error at the 'socket_connect()' step of that client.  It looks to be that for some reason the local network isn't available to PHP running with apache.